# Ripple response like in ListView when RecyclerView item is clicked

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview

When you click on ListView item it respondes by playing some animation like the spreading wave that makes background of item gray for a little time. Thereby user sees which item was clicked. On my RecyclerView, I have implemented, currently there is no any animation like that. I have OnclickListener implemented and app performs all tasks when item is clicked, but it lacks this simple animation. Could anyone help me with this?

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerViewAdapter adapter;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

    String[] data = {"Cola", "Sprite", "Pizza", "Coffee", "Salt", "Pepper", "KitKat"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.myRecyclerView);
        adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(data, this);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        RecyclerView.ItemAnimator itemAnimator = new DefaultItemAnimator();
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(itemAnimator);
    }
}
```

Adapter class:

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private String[] data;
public Context context;

public RecyclerViewAdapter(String[] input, Context c) {
    data = input;
    context = c;
}

public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    public MyOnItemClickListener listener;
    public TextView mTextView;
    public Context cont;

    public MyViewHolder(View v, MyOnItemClickListener l, Context c) {
        super(v);
        mTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.info_text);
        listener = l;
        cont = c;
        v.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        listener.startActivity(cont);
    }

    public static interface MyOnItemClickListener {
        public void startActivity(Context c);
    }
}

@Override
public RecyclerViewAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    final View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_view_item, parent, false);
    MyViewHolder vh = new MyViewHolder(v, new MyViewHolder.MyOnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void startActivity(Context c) {
            Toast.makeText(c, "Item Pressed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Intent intent = new Intent(c, ItemInformationActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("Text", ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.info_text)).getText().toString());
            c.startActivity(intent);

        }
    }, context);
    return vh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.mTextView.setText(data[position]);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.length;
}
}
```

list_view_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
card_view:cardElevation="3dp">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/info_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_android"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: the xml "list_view_item" that you inflate, you create this? or is a default xml that comes with android libraries?, if you create this one, put your code

Comment: @MaxPinto I create a custom list_item layout. It's been added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally figured out how to make touch feedback. Kris Larson was right by saying that I need ripple effect. However I did it by adding this:

```
android:focusable="true"
android:clickable="true"
android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

I didn't need customized ripple. Only default. This now works fine!

Answer (score 1):

You are referring to a `RippleDrawable` [RippleDrawable | Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/RippleDrawable.html)

You can put this as a background for your list item; just make sure it's in `/res/layout-v21` variant as `RippleDrawable` only works on Lollipop and later.